# How to use SRV (or any other) record do redirect a domain?

Tags: azure, dns, cname, http-redirect, srv

So:

- i have a domain example.com
- i have a microsoft azure project at example.cloudapp.net
- i used a CNAME record to make www.example.com work with example.cloudapp.net.

now the problem:

- the domain without the www. part does not work!
- i don't have any options to redirect it in my domain provider account. I can only set: A, MX, CNAME, TXT, AAAA or SRV records.

  - The CNAME and A don't work. I've try CNAME but it dosen't work for example.com. For the A record you have to provide a IP, which is also not very smart for a azure account.

The only record i can imagine to accomplish this is the SRV, but i don't know how to use it properly. Any help or suggestions?

with best regards,

cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more DNS managing question then Azure question.

You can certainly use A record with your Azure deployment. It was at least 6 months back in time (if not longer) when MSFT announced the persistence feature of a VIP (Virtual IP Address). Which means that your deployment (once deployed!) will have 1, non-changing public IP address as long as you do not delete the deployment! That VIP will be persisted across upgrades.

You can find out more about managing deployments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981933.aspx). And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh386336.aspx) there is a full section "Persitence of VIP", where it is explained how your VIP address is persisted.

So, just A record to your VIP address, and it will work as long as you do not delete the deployment. Who needs to access a deleted deployment anyway. Just try to not forget to update the A record when you create new deployment in case you deleted old one.

UPDATE **

I just made couple of checks and I think it's worth trying following SVR record:

_http._tcp 21600 IN SRV 10 10 80 yourservice.cloudapp.net.

Note the dot at the end, it is essential and important!

(I will try it myself as soon as I can - it is definitelly worth exploring this)

UPDATE 2 **

Interesting observation. I made one such record for one of mine domains. However the result is plain redirect to http://yourservice.cloudapp.net/ and not staing on http://mydomain.com/. So the result is - SRV cannot be used. Just use A record to point to your VIP.

Comment: big tnx for your explanation! didn't know about the VIPs or better said that it's non-changing. Have added a A record now, as you suggested. will see what happens :)

Comment: Huge thanks this is amazing,  i was loooking for this all over. Just open the cloud VIP does not change often...

Comment: Web browsers do not query `SRV` records.